# Binary Tree Conditional Insert

Tags: python, data-structures, binary-tree

I am trying to write a logic to insert a node into a binary tree.
The node looks like this

```
    
   class BinTree:
    def __init__(self, Id):
        self.Id = Id
        self.NodeCounter = 1
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
```

I need to insert a new node only if it doesnt exist in the tree but increment the counter if it exists already.

As of now, what im doing is whenever i get a new element to insert, i first search it in the binary tree, if the node is found i increment the NodeCounter by 1, otherwise I again start traversing from root node and then go and insert the new node

The problem here is that for every new node, i am traversing the tree twice which i dont want… And when i am trying to search and insert at the same time,the counters get messed because of recursion.

Is there a way I can achieve this?
Any tips would be appreciated

Comment: How are you traversing the tree? If you're using recursion, then you presumably have a base case. Why not set the node if you reach the base case?

Comment: Can you explain how "the counters get messed" when you insert and search at the same time? Can you please share the code you've attempted?

Answer (score 0):

> i first search it in the binary tree

...this would only be an efficient process if your binary tree is a binary *search* tree (BST). I'll assume that is what we are talking about.

> if the node is found i increment the NodeCounter by 1, otherwise I again start traversing from root node and then go and insert the new node

Why would you start from the root again? When you did the search and didn't find the node, there was a last node that you visited. Just attach the new node to it.

Here is a possible implementation:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, id):
        self.id = id
        self.nodeCounter = 1
        self.left = None
        self.right = None


class BinTree:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None

    def add(self, id):
        self.root = self.addrecur(self.root, id)

    def addrecur(self, node, id):
        if not node:
            node = Node(id)
        elif id == node.id:
            node.nodeCounter += 1
        elif id < node.id:
            node.left = self.addrecur(node.left, id)
        else:
            node.right = self.addrecur(node.right, id)
        return node

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.indented(self.root)
    
    def indented(self, node, indent=""):
        if not node:
            return ""
        return (self.indented(node.right, indent + "  ")
              + f"{indent}{node.id} ({node.nodeCounter})\n"
              + self.indented(node.left, indent + "  "))


tree = BinTree()
tree.add(4)
tree.add(2)
tree.add(3)
tree.add(2)
tree.add(6)
tree.add(5)
tree.add(5)
print(tree)
```

This outputs the tree in side-ways view (root at left) with the node count in parentheses:

```
  6 (1)
    5 (2)
4 (1)
    3 (1)
  2 (2)
```